how to make the step in decorations.markings scale
How can I make the step in the decorations.markings library scale with the rest of the picture?
The following code should have two markings in the centimeter, not one, when I scale by 0.5.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[
        help lines
    ] (0,0) grid (3,3);
    \draw[
        decoration={markings,
        % the 1cm in the following line does not scale, how can I make it scale?
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 1cm with {\draw (0,-2pt) -- (0,2pt);},
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    ] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



With a \newcommand{\myscale}{0.5} and mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \myscale cm
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\myscale}{0.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\myscale]
    \draw[
        help lines
    ] (0,0) grid (3,3);
    \draw[
        decoration={markings,
        % the 1cm in the following line does not scale, how can I make it scale?
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \myscale cm with {\draw (0,-2pt) -- (0,2pt);},
        },
        postaction={decorate}
    ] (0,0) -- (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


